# Remove decimal point from number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the decimal, but keep all of the digits.

All I can think of is to find the length of the number and find out which power of 10 it's just larger than, then multiply. Although, I can't find how to find the length of a number.

Comment: Are you saying that a number such as `1234.5678` should become `12345678`?

Comment: *Stringfy* and *Remove the dot*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i should not do it but look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLF3b/1/)

```
var d = 109.65;
var s = d + '';
s =s.replace('.', '');
s = parseInt(s);
alert(s);
```

Comment: Will it be treated as a number to which I can do math?

Comment: convert it bnack to digit  usinign parseInt

Answer (score 5):

```
var newnumber = parseInt(num.toString().replace(".", ""), 10);
```

Comment: It's not neccessary explicit to specify 10 in this case

Comment: force of habit with the ,10 to ensure decimal - I commented on your answer the same time you commented here :p

Comment: @DanielGrankin it's always best practice to include the radix when using parseInt

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
parseInt(num.toString().replace('.', ''))
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter, as stringed number will never start with "0" unless it is 0.  If however stringed number was for instance "010" it would be treated as oct without the optional radix parameter (10) on the parseInt call.

Comment: Question is about decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace`:

```
var num = 1234.5678;
alert((num + '').replace('.', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more generic way which will remove all non numerics you could use:

```
var num = 1234.5678;
var str = new String(num); 
alert(str.replace(/[^0-9|-]/g, ""));
```

and if it needs to be a number afterwards just wrap it in a parseInt.

Comment: what about the - sign for negative numbers? that's gonna change things!

Comment: Good point, have added an or into the regex.